# For google firebase dynamic link, wiith preview page off (efr=1), the link always redirect you to app store even if the app is installed

Tags: ios, firebase, app-store

Seems a few people had the issues too, but didn't figure a solution yet. For example I am having exactly the same [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252185/firebase-dynamic-link-always-goes-to-app-store-url-even-if-the-app-is-installed).

Also according to [this](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/282) a reliable way to test if the universal link set up properly or not is to test the link in the notes app, which works for me. (Also works if I send the message with the link to myself.) However I can't open the app directly in most chat apps (eg. slack, discord) nor safari. On the other hand they works with the preview page on.

Anyone had a fix / workaround? Or that's just how it is (saw this might be issues with app trying to open the link in there build in browser and prevent redirecting somehow ?)

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: facing the same issue on slack it is not working it is opening the preview page and takes me to apple store and not to the app

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, enabling both universal links and custom url schemes for my dynamic link solved the issue.

Dynamic Links -> Edit Link -> Define link behavior for iOS

This is the setup:

[image: configuration on firebase console]

Comment: What do you mean "enable"? Somewhere in firebase console? Could you please clarify your answer?

Comment: Enable in the firebase console meaning having all the options selected as in a screenshot.