# Firebase Dynamic Link behaving strangely in Chrome iOS

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

We're having trouble with the following Firebase Dynamic Link in Chrome iOS (tested on 72.0.3626.74): https://carvana.page.link/?link=https://www.carvana.com&isi=1273426583&ibi=com.carvana.copilot&cid=4115817180136449045&_icp=1

On a device without the target app installed, the link is expected to open the app store.

When following the link on a device with Chrome set as the default browser, the "preview page" opens and immediately displays a dialog reading "This page will open in another application":

[image: Step 1]

Tapping "Open" dismisses the dialog but does not open the app store:

[image: Step 2]

Tapping the "OPEN" HTML button then triggers the same dialog again:

[image: Step 3]

This time, tapping "Open" opens the store as expected:

[image: Step 4]

Opening the link in Safari behaves as expected, rendering the preview page and prompting to open the store only after tapping "OPEN".

Comment: Also interesting to note that the app icon doesn't display properly on the preview page in Chrome, where it does in Safari.

Comment: Googling around, I was able to find another FDL—the first I found that points to the App Store—that displays the same behavior: https://funrun3.page.link/tp

Comment: Do you have `.forcedRedirectEnabled` set?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be an ongoing issue with Forced Redirects in FDL. You can read up on it [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1244).

Basically the workaround until a permanent fix is to disable Forced Redirects. It is annoying, however the App Preview page link *is* more reliable than Forced Redirect.

```
FIRDynamicLinkNavigationInfoParameters *navigationInfoParameters = [FIRDynamicLinkNavigationInfoParameters parameters];
    navigationInfoParameters.forcedRedirectEnabled = 0;
    components.navigationInfoParameters = navigationParams;
```

[Other users have reported related issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252185/firebase-dynamic-link-always-goes-to-app-store-url-even-if-the-app-is-installed), and some have found wokrarounds for FDL Forced Redirect issues similar to the one you are reporting.

I believe that issue is due to the Forced Redirect not correctly determining the IOS version of the client. The Forced Redirect uses a different route than the App Preview page. As stated above, [even the FDL documentation says that the App Preview page is more reliable than Forced Redirect.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create)

I hope this helps